# Exporting bitmapCache with a custom background color

Tags: caching, background, easeljs

I need to export the image data url of a large stage content hosted on a canvas.

The quickest way I found is to cache the needed stage area then call `stage.bitmapCache.getCachedDataURL()` method, that gives me the cachedBitmap data url of desired content.

My problem is that the background is transparent and I need it white. I can't find a way to compose a white background and the bitmapCache using easeljs library (version 1.0).

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance.

Fabrizio

Answer (score 0):

I tried this workaround that's working:

- Create a shape sized like the desired area.
- Add it to the stage in bottommost position with `stage.addChildAt(shape, 0);`
- Place it at the area origin: `shape.x = stageArea.x, shape.y = stageArea.y;`
- Cache the desired stage area.
- Get the data url with `stage.bitmapCache.getCachedDataURL();`
- Get rid of the background shape with `stage.removeChildAt(0);`

Anyway, if someone has a better solution using bitmap manipulation, I'll be glad to know it.

Comment: That's how I would do it :)